# ChartJS: Blank page | what is going wrong?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am a novice at Chart JS.  I am trying to learn from example.  I created the following HTML page with CSV data that should be plotted using ChartJS... but it is blank!  What is going wrong?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>My Chart.js Chart</title>
</head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/xlsx@0.14.3/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datasource@0.1.0"> </script>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script>
      var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
      var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                                  type: 'bar',
                                  plugins: [ChartDataSource],
                                  options: {
                                    plugins: {
                                      datasource: {
                                        url: 'precipitation.csv'
                                                  }
                                              }
                                            }
                                    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSV file has been [**paste binned here**](https://pastebin.com/iCEPuECx) for your reference.

I am using the `chartjs-plugin-datasource` on [this git](https://github.com/nagix/chartjs-plugin-datasource).

Comment: @nagix, any help on this please? :)

Comment: As a note to self, [etting up a simple HTTP server](https://www.tecmint.com/python-simplehttpserver-to-create-webserver-or-serve-files-instantly/) in the folder where the HTML and JS are, helps.  `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the folder of interest.  Then launch a webbrowser and access `<ip address>:8000` to launch the `index.html` in that folder.  If this `index.html` has JS in it, it will launch with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem didn't come from your code. Your project trie to access data from an external services and is blocked by [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors) policy. The simplest way to avoid this error is to execute your code in a local server.
You can use this simple npm package ([serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve)) or [other](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/start-a-web-server-with-one-terminal-command-on-os-x/) to serve your code locally.

With the serve package the process is quite simple.

**Install serve package via NPM**

```
npm i -g serve
```

**Go to the root of your project and launch serve**

```
serve
```

After the local server is initialise, you can access to it in your browser via the local ip provided.

Moreover, I recommend you to use [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) or [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) (means that the identifier can’t be reassigned) instead of var since ES2015.

Comment: Well, I replaced both `var` with `let` and then with `const`.  I also included the absolute file path.. Neither had an effect  `:(`  Would it be possible for you to share your code snippet in your answer?

Comment: Oh no sorry it's not just that, you also need to make a http local server to use Chart.js in order to avoid CORS policy errors.

Comment: If the answer seems correct, please validate it in order to close the thread.

Comment: I assume your solution has the same effect as hosting the HTML/JS on a service such as GitHub?  This worked for me -- having the HTML and JS on my GitHub page.

Comment: Yes, logically on your GitHub page, there will be no error. If you satisfied by my answer, accept it in order to close the subject. ;)

Comment: As a note to self, [etting up a simple HTTP server](https://www.tecmint.com/python-simplehttpserver-to-create-webserver-or-serve-files-instantly/) in the folder where the HTML and JS are, helps.  `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the folder of interest.  Then launch a webbrowser and access `<ip address>:8000` to launch the `index.html` in that folder.  If this `index.html` has JS in it, it will launch with no problem.

Comment: Why did you unaccept my answer ? It's seems to working for you. The comment overhead is the same solution I gave you with a difference service (Python Http server instead of serve).

Comment: Hi @ThibaultWalterspieler.  I do appreciate your answer but it was more of a comment without a demonstration.  I would be happy to re-accept it if you can update your "answer" with a quantifiable example.

Comment: Hi @dearN, I updated my answer. I hope that my answer will satisfy you ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, they have the datasource property nested like this.

```
options: {
    plugins: {
        datasource: {
            url: 'precipitation.csv'
        }
    }
}
```

Does that make a difference?

Comment: It did not... then again, I am not sure if I am nesting (indenting?) it right.  I updated my Q with nested code (or what I Think is nested code)